# TypeError: QgsRubberBand(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'bool'

Tags: qgis-plugins, digitizing

I am trying to install the 'Digitizing Tools' plugin in QGIS version 3.30.0-'s-Hertogenbosch but am getting the below error. I am not a GIS tech and have no idea what this means and google is not giving me many answers. Could someone explain in layman terms and methods for troubleshooting?

[image]

Comment: Bug recently reported [#60](https://github.com/bstroebl/DigitizingTools/issues/60)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is QgsRubberBand was changed in recent versions of QGIS. You have to use an old version of Qgis with this plugin (3.16 seems to work), wait for the developer to update the plugin or go into the Python code of the plugin yourself to make a simple change.

First, search for the file "dtmovesidebydistance.py" (the screenshot you showed has the info of where to find it) and put this in the top, where the imports are:

```
from qgis.core import QgsWkbTypes
```

Then, change the error line (originally line 42) for this one:

```
self.rbl = QgsRubberBand(self.canvas, QgsWkbTypes.GeometryType.Line)
```

This is not guaranteed to solve further problems, since the plugin apparently isn't updated for this version of Qgis.

The simple answer is, then, use another version of Qgis (you should try LTR, which is 3.28).